# Firestore data model for posts and comments

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am currently watching a how-to create an instagram clone for Swift and want to understand the data model for the comments.

What is the purpose of using a model for the comments like:

post-comment (key = post-id) and comments

[image: post-comment]

[image: comments]

over something like this, where every comment has the post-id in it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what *exactly* they're building, and the types of queries they need to support for the app, one can only guess that this post-comments collection satisfies the need for a query to find out which comments are a part of which posts, while still allowing queries that search all posts or all comments.  You should find the part of the tutorial that queries this collection to find out what it's trying to do.

This tutorial might be kind of old, because this sort of thing would be a little bit easier to express today using collection group queries.